# Mouse click on Flash element in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

At my university we're using a very shitty Flash video player for the recorded lectures. It's not possible to download the recordings, so my solution is to record the lectures with quicktime using an applescript script(Completely legal by the way). In this way, I can choose my own playback speed and it's much easier to pause/play the video. You can see an example here:
http://vc.au.dk/videos/video/9115/

The problem is that my script need to click on a Flash element in the video player to switch to another presentation layout (for instance a zoom in on the black board). You can see an example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQeU9.png.

I have tried something like the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
  click at {123,456}
end tell
```

But this does not do the click. 
It just says:

> "group 5 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of splitter group 1 of window "LifeSize UVC Video Center - Computability & Logic F2020 - 06 March 2020" of application process "Safari" of application "System Events""

Do you have any suggestion to how I can click this particular button via applescript?

If you need more information, please let me know!

Thank you very much!

Comment: I answered this on Reddit for you. In short: you can't. But full explanation is given on Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

If clicking on a particular point is how you want to go about this, use cliclick. You can trigger it using AppleScript's `do shell script`

You'll have to use the full path to cliclick to get it to work (like /usr/local/bin/cliclick)

So, the `do shell script` cliclick version of your example would be:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:123,456"
```

https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/